# Replace </div> with empty string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace *end tag* div with empty string

my code is:

```
$('#textDiv').html().replace(/'</div>'/g,'').replace(/<div>/g,'\n')
```

The html is:

```
<div id='textDiv'>
 <div>first line</div>
 <div>Second line</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get this output "first line\nSecond line", but I get error:"Uncaught Error: Module parse failed:"

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @j08691 bad UX? I thought that would be obvious... /s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your forward slash, and remove the single quotes.

```
$('#textDiv').html().replace(/<\/div>/g,'').replace(/<div>/g,'\n')
```

Comment: @TalYaron You should try this before you accept it because it doesn't work. `.replace()` won't change the original string, it returns the modified string which you then can use.

Comment: @j08691, I tryied it and i worked... this is the code I am using right now in my project and it works: $('#findingDescription').html().replace(/<div>/g,'\n').replace(/<\/div>/g,'')

Comment: @J08691, you don't know if the OP is trying to replace HTML on the page, or simply get a string replacement for other use.  You pointed out a valid concern on another answer, which was helpful (and which I missed) but simply trying to get your answer accepted instead is not helpful to the OP or to the site in general.

Comment: @TalYaron No it doesn't. See https://jsfiddle.net/vt8vkz3a/ and inspect the source.

Comment: @Daniel Where am I trying to get my answer accepted? I'm simply pointing out a critical flaw in your answer. And if the OP wants to use the HTML from one place in another, they should expressly note that.

Answer (score 4):

`/` is a special RegEx character, you need to escape it with `\/`. Also, remove the quotes --> `/<\/div>/g`

Comment: Won't work with the single quotes still.  Remove those, and you're good to go!

Comment: Yours came in while I was writing mine.  Love all these quick answers!

Comment: It worked! thanks. I changed the code to
.html().replace(/<div>/g,'\n').replace(/<\/div>/g,'')

Comment: @Tal I have updated my answer, you can do that with one regex and one `replace`.

Comment: Good call on doing both with one `replace`.  @Tal: this is more performant and a better plan overall!

Comment: I have tried this solution (.replace(/<\/?div>/g,''), but I need the <div> to become /n...

Comment: But the one replace answer doesn't do what the OP asked for. They said they wanted a newline between the divs, which that won't do.

Comment: Ah that's perfectly right, sorry. I didn't notice that. OP wants `\n`, removing the Regex combo. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since `.replace()` returns the modified value and doesn't change the original string, you need to use it within the callback of `.html()`. And as others noted you need to remove the quotes you used and escape the slash:

```js
$('#textDiv').html(function() {
  return $(this).html().replace(/<\/div>/g, '').replace(/<div>/g, '\n')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='textDiv'>
  <div>first line</div>
  <div>Second line</div>
</div>
```